# file_put_contents overwriting data instead of appendin it

Tags: php

I have been trying to write a simple php script that adds two numbers and append the result to a text file.Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>RESULT PAGE</title>  
</head>
<body>
<h4>Number 1 is <?php echo $_POST['num1']; ?></h4>
<h4>Number 2 is <?php echo $_POST['num2']; ?></h4>
<h3>The result of adding above numbers is <?php
$num1=$_POST['num1'];
$num2=$_POST['num2'];
    $result=$num1 + $num2;
file_put_contents("test.txt",$result,FILE_APPEND);
echo $result;
?></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever the script is executed previous data is replaced instead of adding data to the new line.
I am currently using UBUNTU 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Above code works for me. Unless you have another process working on that file, I don't see problem with the code.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?
Also, could you test it using lower level functions? So replacing your file_put_contents with:

    $stream = fopen('test.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($stream, $result);
    fclose($stream);

Comment: @Tularis i am using php 5.0 and yeah i tried writing using fwrite() but with no success..:/

Comment: That is strange; fopen with the 'a+' parameter has been around since early PHP 4.1 (if I remember well), so it should work fine in 5.0. Though file_put_contents was added in PHP5.0, so it might be a bug in there. You do know PHP 5.5 is the current stable version, right? :)

Comment: user fopen and fwrite with proper arguments

Comment: The code works as expected in isolation, so either you've not shared something with us or it's a bug (highly doubt so).

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that .. The purpose of **`FILE_APPEND`** is to append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

Well, It works fine for me. Try coupling with **`LOCK_EX`**

```
file_put_contents("test.txt",$result,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: LOCK_EX was only introduced in 5.1; besides that, it wouldn't likely change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To append the value as a newline, you need to send two escaped newline arguments when writing to the file, like so:

```
file_put_contents("test.txt",$result . "\n\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Otherwise they will be written to the same line (last line in file).

If this doesn't help, make sure to check the file permissions to ensure apache (or whatever your webserver group is) has write permissions.

Comment: OP mentioned that previous data is gone, not that all data is now on one line.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively u can try this,

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'w');
fseek($fp, SEEK_END);//places pointer to the end.
fwrite($fp, $results);
```

?>

Comment: fseek will set the pointer to end.and then when you'll write it'll append not replace.

Comment: replacing the thing with a simple fopen('somefile.txt','a') negates the need for an fseek

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. In my case, I had 2 file_put_contents in different files, in one of them I had FILE_APPEND and in the second file not. The issue was solved adding FILE_APPEND to both file_put_contents functions.
Check if you're executing file_put_contents calling the same "test.txt" file, in another line or php file and add the FILE_APPEND attribute.